# Написать класс с использованием ООП python

Tags: python

Необходимо написать класс `MiniController`, в котором будут атрибуты `chanel` и `volume`, а также три метода:

- `ch_plus()` - увеличивает кол-во каналов на один по кругу от 1 до 5. После пятого опять идёт первый канал.
- `vol_plus()` - увеличивает громкость по +1 полосе до 30 полосок (это максимальный уровень звука)
- `vol_minus()` - уменьшает уровень звука по -1 полосе до 0 полос.
  Телевизор всегда включается на 1 канале с уровнем звука 10.

Мое решение:

```
class MiniController:
    def __init__(self):
        self.chanel = 1
        self.volume = "||||||||||"
    def ch_plus(self):
        self.chanel += 1
    def vol_plus(self):
        self.volume + "|"
    def vol_minus(self):
        self.volume = self.volume[:-1]
    
pult = MiniController()
for _ in range(3):
    pult.ch_plus()
print(pult.chanel)
for _ in range(15):
    pult.ch_plus()
print(pult.chanel)
for _ in range(50):
    pult.vol_plus()
print(pult.volume)
pult.vol_minus()
print(pult.volume)
```

Не могу сделать `ch_plus()`, чтобы кол-во каналов увеличивалось на один по кругу от 1 до 5. После пятого опять идёт первый и `vol_plus()` увеличивает громкость по +1 полосе до 30 полосок (это максимальный уровень звука) и `vol_minus()` - уменьшает уровень звука по -1 полосе до 0 полос.
После запуска должно быть:

```
4
4
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

В моем решении не так. Как исправить и сделать правильно?

Comment: Ну проверяй перед увеличением. Если 5, то делай 0. И измени заголовок. У тебя вопрос не "написать класс", а реализовать изменение переменной по кругу или типа того

Comment: Кол-во каналов получилось сделать:  def ch_plus(self):
        if self.chanel == 5:
            self.chanel -= 1
        elif self.chanel < 4:
            self.chanel +=1 Но со зуком, чтобы по кругу пока никак. Вариант такой, но несовсем правильный: def vol_plus(self):     
        if len(self.volume) < 29:
            self.volume + "|"
    def vol_minus(self):
        if len(self.volume)== 30:
            self.volume = self.volume[:-1] Как сделать правильно?

Comment: Написано: "Если 5, то делай 0". Сделано: "если 5, то равно 4". Видишь разницу?

Comment: Ok. Только "Если 5, то делай 1" def ch_plus(self):
        if self.chanel == 5:
            self.chanel = 1
        elif self.chanel != 5:
            self.chanel += 1

Comment: Точно так же по аналогии.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from itertools import cycle

class MiniController:
    def __init__(self):
        self._c = cycle(range(1, 6))
        self.chanel = next(self._c)
        self._v = 10

    def ch_plus(self):
        self.chanel = next(self._c)
    def vol_plus(self):
        self._v = min(self._v + 1, 30)
    def vol_minus(self):
        self._v = max(self._v - 1, 0)

    @property
    def volume(self):
        return '|' * self._v


pult = MiniController()
for _ in range(3):
    pult.ch_plus()
print(pult.chanel)
for _ in range(15):
    pult.ch_plus()
print(pult.chanel)
for _ in range(50):
    pult.vol_plus()
print(pult.volume)
pult.vol_minus()
print(pult.volume)
```

---

```
4
4
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Вроде так тоже работает:
class MiniController:
    def __init__(self):
        self.chanel = 1
        self.volume = "||||||||||"
    def ch_plus(self):
        if self.chanel == 5:
            self.chanel = 1
        elif self.chanel != 5:
            self.chanel += 1
    def vol_plus(self):
        if 10 <= len(self.volume) < 30:
            self.volume = self.volume + "|"
    def vol_minus(self):
        if len(self.volume) == 30:
            self.volume = self.volume[:-1]
```

Comment: Ошибка в vol_minus()

Comment: Как правильно сделать vol_minus(self)?

Comment: перечитать задание и сравнить с тем, что написано в коде

Comment: Пока только такое решение: def vol_minus(self):
        if 0 <= len(self.volume) :
            self.volume = self.volume[:-1]

Comment: примерно так. Только вместо ``<=`` нужно ``<``